# How to wait for presence of element and particular text in element?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to wait for the presence of an element with specific text in it.
I want to fetch the info from that element in the moment the element is present and has text in it. I appears sometime after  submitting a form and normaly fills with info a little later.
My current solution looks like this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, MAXIMUM_LOAD_TIME)
    try:
        wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"IdOfElement")))
        wait.until(ec.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, "IdOfElement"), "theText"))
        data = self._extract_data()
    except TimeoutException:
        raise WebsiteTimeoutError(MAXIMUM_LOAD_TIME)
```

This runs perfectly in >99% of the cases but now it happened that i got an error on `ec.text_to_be_present_in_element`.

The error was:

```
  File "my/Path", line 436, in  _scrape_quote
    wait.until(ec.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, "IdOfElement"), "theText"))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 210, in __call__
    return self.text in element_text
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Apparently the element dissapeared again. Is my assumption right? What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: share the actual url. Without that no way to know.

Comment: Is that the full error?

Comment: @AbhishekRai url is not sharable. An this should not depend on a specific website. I want a solution that always throws a timeoutException when Element and Text are never together and is readable.

Comment: @DMart added full error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the `text_to_be_present_in_element` implementation it assume the value is never None.

```
    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            element_text = _find_element(driver, self.locator).text
            return self.text in element_text
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False
```

If the value of `element_text` is None (which can be sometime), it will throw you an exception

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Now your code is a little cumbersome as you need to ensure the element is present first, then retrieve the same element to find the proper value. There is no class in the EC module that offer both at the same time. So how about implementing your class.

You can implement a class that will ensure it is present and at the same time fix the issue to handle the case of None in the text return.

```
class FindPresenceOfTextInElement(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, text):
        self.locator = locator
        self.text = text

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            text = driver.find_element(*self.locator).text
            return self.text in text
        except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, TypeError):
            return False
```

Then your code becomes:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, MAXIMUM_LOAD_TIME)
    try:
        wait.until(FindPresenceOfTextInElement((By.ID,"IdOfElement")))
        data = self._extract_data()
    except TimeoutException:
        raise WebsiteTimeoutError(MAXIMUM_LOAD_TIME)
```

You will need the following imports:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
```

**UPDATE**

AS the above is the best approach, I believe, you could have work around it by adding the exception handler in the wait obj as follow:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=(TypeError, ))
```

If you add the `NoSuchElementException` as well, you basically added to ensure element is present too.